# i cant insert data in ms access database through textbox

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledb

I have a database and i use MS ACCESS 2007. I wanted to insert data into the database through textbox. I have this code below but I got errors.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\Sisc-stronghold\mis!\wilbert.beltran\DataBase\DataStructure.accdb");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username, Password)" + "VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
```

and here are the errors

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at VirginiTEAcorp.Form3.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\12-014s\My Documents\applications\Database\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form3.cs:line 34

Comment: "but I got errors. " - what errors?

Comment: you have created parameters, but not used them! .....why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try this code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userinfo (FirstName, LastName, Age, Address, Course)" + "VALUES (@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Age, @Address, @Course)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", textBox5.Text);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            clear();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
                conn.Close();
            }
            dataholder();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

if you'll declare parameters. you may have to used them in a way. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared parameters but not used them,If you are using following statement then there is no need to use parameters

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username, Password)" + "VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
```

But if you want to use parameters then you neeed to change commandtext as follow...

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username, Password) VALUES (@UserName,@Password)";
```

Comment: SQL injection anyone?