# not displaying data in gridview when user selects between dates

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

```
 OleDbConn.ole = "SELECT InvoiceDate,InvoiceNo,Customer,SalesPerson,TotalAmount"
 +" FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN "
 + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
 + " AND " + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
 + " AND (InvoiceNo LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text 
 + "%' OR SalesPerson LIKE '%"+ txtSearch.Text 
 + "%' OR Customer LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%') GROUP BY InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,Customer,SalesPerson,TotalAmount " 
 +"ORDER BY InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo DESC"; //here is my search query

dgw.Rows.Add(
     Convert.ToDateTime(OleDbConn.dr[0]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), 
     OleDbConn.dr[1].ToString(),OleDbConn.dr[2].ToString(),
     OleDbConn.dr[3].ToString(), 
     Strings.FormatNumber(OleDbConn.dr[4]).ToString(), 
     Strings.FormatNumber(OleDbConn.dr[4]).ToString()); //adding data to gridview
```

when a user selects the dates between its supposed to show data in gridview but its not, code works well in sql but its failing in ms-access

Comment: What a mess.. please edit your question and make it more readable.

Comment: Should it be just closed as dup of one of many https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+msaceess+paramtrized+query like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105872/i-cant-insert-data-in-ms-access-database-through-textbox?

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more readable.

Comment: ved prakash i hav edited it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you comparing date as stringS? use Parameterization and also use `<>` instead for Between while comparing dates; You should use something like this:

```
OleDbConn.ole  = " Query-Here WHERE InvoiceDate > @startDate AND" + 
                 " InvoiceDate < @endDate AND rest-of-code-here"
```

Now pass the values as parametrs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You should add # before and after static date values and date format should be like `MM/dd/yyyy`

```
OleDbConn.ole = "SELECT InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo, Customer, SalesPerson, TotalAmount" 
    + " FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN #" 
    + startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# AND #" 
    + endDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") 
    + "# AND (InvoiceNo LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text 
    + "%' OR SalesPerson LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text 
    + "%' OR Customer LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%') GROUP BY InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,Customer,SalesPerson,TotalAmount " 
    + "ORDER BY InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo DESC"; //here is my search query
```

Comment: when i add them i get data type mismatch

Comment: Could you write exact exception message? and is it .net or sql exception?

Comment: it doesnot show any exception error, that code works well in sql database but when i use ms-access and select bewteen dates it does not display data in gridview

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this one?

```
 OleDbConn.ole = "SELECT InvoiceDate,InvoiceNo,Customer,SalesPerson,TotalAmount"
 +" FROM Invoice WHERE CDate(InvoiceDate) BETWEEN #"
 + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
 + "# AND #" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
 + "# AND (InvoiceNo LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text 
 + "%' OR SalesPerson LIKE '%"+ txtSearch.Text 
 + "%' OR Customer LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%') GROUP BY InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,Customer,SalesPerson,TotalAmount " 
 +"ORDER BY InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo DESC";
```

Comment: getting this System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression

Comment: Sorry. Forgot you used MS Access.

Comment: any other tip thnx anyway for quick response